# Angularjs & Facebook Api: How can i attach controller function in a 'onlogin' attr in a facebook button

Tags: angularjs

Good day mate, i have implemented facebook login api to my web app using angulars framework. 
my question is it is possible to attach controller function in a 'onlogin' attribute? or is there another way to call controller function if the user logged in. this is how i construct the button

NOTE: i tried to add ng-click also in the button but ng-click ether is not working

```
<fb:login-button 
show-faces="true" 
max-rows="1"
size="large"
scope="public_profile,email"
onlogin="test()"
>
</fb:login-button>
```

the errors says :

```
 VM22638 sdk.js:108 Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
```

a help much appreciated and thanks you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind Facebook onlogin event to customized button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136491/how-to-bind-facebook-onlogin-event-to-customized-button)

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136491/how-to-bind-facebook-onlogin-event-to-customized-button/53568221#53568221

Comment: As far as I can tell this method is still required if you want to take an *explicit* action after the login button has been clicked, as opposed to an implicit one based on just being 'connected' to the app already